# Defining group generic functions in an R package

Tags: r, r-s4

I'm having trouble defining a group generic within an R package that I'm writing.

Here is a fairly minimal example:

```
setGroupGeneric('FooBarFunctions', function(x, y) NULL)

setGeneric('foo', group = 'FooBarFunctions', function(x, y) standardGeneric('foo'))
setGeneric('bar', group = 'FooBarFunctions', function(x, y) standardGeneric('bar'))

setMethod('foo', signature(x = 'ANY', y = 'ANY'),
function(x, y)
  cat(sprintf('foo,ANY (%s),ANY (%s)\n', x, y)))

setMethod('bar', signature(x = 'ANY', y = 'ANY'),
function(x, y)
  cat(sprintf('bar,ANY (%s),ANY (%s)\n', x, y)))

setMethod('FooBarFunctions', signature(x = 'character', y = 'ANY'),
function(x, y)
  cat(sprintf('FooBarFunctions,character (%s),ANY (%s)\n', x, y)))
```

If I paste this code into an R terminal, then everything works as expected:

```
> foo(1, 2)
foo,ANY (1),ANY (2)
> bar(1, 2)
bar,ANY (1),ANY (2)
> foo('a', 2)
FooBarFunctions,character (a),ANY (2)
> bar('a', 2)
FooBarFunctions,character (a),ANY (2)
```

However, as soon as I try to build this into a package I run into the following error:

```
$ R CMD INSTALL .
* installing to library ‘~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15’
* installing *source* package ‘anRpackage’ ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  ‘anRpackage’ 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
**Error in .setupMethodsTables(generic) : 
  trying to get slot "group" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots**
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/anRpackage’
```

I'm using the default output from package.skeleton(), having added:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

into the NAMESPACE file

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Has anyone else been able to reproduce this problem?

Comment: No one been able to repoduce this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can get this to work if I run the code on load. The key here is the `evalqOnLoad` call

```
evalqOnLoad({

    setGroupGeneric('FooBarFunctions', function(x, y) NULL)

    setGeneric('foo', group = 'FooBarFunctions', function(x, y) standardGeneric('foo'))
    setGeneric('bar', group = 'FooBarFunctions', function(x, y) standardGeneric('bar'))

    setMethod('foo', signature(x = 'ANY', y = 'ANY'),
    function(x, y)
      cat(sprintf('foo,ANY (%s),ANY (%s)\n', x, y)))

    setMethod('bar', signature(x = 'ANY', y = 'ANY'),
    function(x, y)
      cat(sprintf('bar,ANY (%s),ANY (%s)\n', x, y)))

    setMethod('FooBarFunctions', signature(x = 'character', y = 'ANY'),
    function(x, y)
      cat(sprintf('FooBarFunctions,character (%s),ANY (%s)\n', x, y)))

})
```

in a package 'bla' :

```
> require( bla )
Le chargement a nécessité le package : bla
> foo(1, 2 )
foo,ANY (1),ANY (2)
> bar(1, 2 )
bar,ANY (1),ANY (2)
> foo("a", 2 )
FooBarFunctions,character (a),ANY (2)
> bar("a", 2 )
FooBarFunctions,character (a),ANY (2)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer - it certainly allows the package to build, but I find that the foo and bar functions don't get exported from the package any more... When you run `require( bla )`, is that in a new R session?

Comment: Hmmm... odd.  I run `R CMD INSTALL bla`, then start a new R and run `require(bla)`, I get `Error: could not find function "foo"` when I try to run `foo(1, 2)`. What is in your NAMESPACE file? I have `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")`.  What version of R are you using?  I'm on 2.15.0.

Comment: That's interesting - your original solution seems to work for me on R 2.15.2 (on Windows), but the functions don't to be exported for me in 2.15.0 (on Linux)...  Maybe there's a change in NAMESPACE behavior between versions 2.15.0 and 2.15.2?

Comment: This was R 2.15.1 on OSX Lion with the same namespace you have.

Comment: Yes, that works on R 2.15.1 or later.  It seems like a bit of a 'work-around' - I don't imagine that the core R packages are written like that?